# Mercurial hook to list outdated branches which are behind their parents

Tags: version-control, merge, mercurial, hook, branch

We use mercurial workflow with one stable branch (default), one unstable (develop) and feature branches. We want feature branches to always contain all changesets from parent branch(es) to simplify merging them back. Is there any example hooks to prevent adding commits to feature branches which are behind their parent branch? Github has a similar message when your branch is behind master.

Generally there are two scenarios:

1. Enforce feature-branch owners to sync with upstream branch before pushing new changes (pushed changegroup should be not behind its parent)
2. Periodically check for list of child branches which became outdated due to recent commits in their parent branches and nudge branch owners to sync or close it

Answer (score 0):

It's basically two separate things you ask:

There is no pre-made hook for denying push when not merged with default which I know of, but maybe some google-foo might reveal some. However it should be quite straight forward to create one:

- By my understanding of your requirements: you want to check an incoming transaction to contain only commits to the non-default branch, if their latest commit is a merge of default into it. This is a task for a server-side hook of the pretxnchangegroup kind; there you can analyse the incoming transaction and the changesets it contains and reject the transaction if it does not meet your requirements. Therein check the latest commit to a feature branch (or better non-default and non-develop(?)) to be a merge commit with default or develop.

As to periodic checking with the central repository:

- The periodic checking for outdated child branches is a client-side action. You could for instance create here a commit hook. Thus querying hg incoming each time a commit is made. Or simply make a crontab entry client-side and trim the output to your desire.